# Increase loop index in twig

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

Below is my code. I want to increase J loop index in between inner loop so I have incremented J variable but it is not working.

```
`{% for j in 0..(products|length-1) %}
{% for f in 0..(rows-1) %}
{% set j = j + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}`
```

Is there any other way to increase loop index?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: you could access to the parent loop context with `loop.parent.j`  as example, but seems you can't modify the value

Comment: @Matteo, yes we cant modify value with loop.parent.j

Comment: @DarkBee, I want to display all products divided in specific number of rows. Suppose, there are 5 products. It should be display in 3 rows so for 5 products there will be 2 sets of products : 1 with 3 products and 1 with 2 product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to alter the loop indeces of `twig` due to the fact of how the loops are compiled

`{% for i in 1..5 %}` for example gets compiled as

```
$context['_seq'] = twig_ensure_traversable(range(1, 5));
foreach ($context['_seq'] as $context["_key"] => $context["i"]) {
    //..
}
```

I do have another aproach for you to solve this with `twig`

```
{% set rows = 2 %}
{% set items = ((products|length) / rows) | round %}

{% for product in products %}
    {% if loop.index0 % items == 0 %}
<div class="row">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="product">
        {{ product }}
    </div>
    {% if loop.index % items == 0 or loop.last %}
</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working with little changes. It should be {% set items = rows %} then it works perfect.

Comment: awesome explanation! +1